# How to display a badge in Trigger.io's native tab bar?

Tags: trigger.io

Is there a way to create a numeric badge in Trigger.io's native tab bar?
I'm looking to achieve something like so:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps just two versions of your tabbar buttons, one with no notifications, and one with a notifications star - that way you wouldn't need different whole logos for all the possible counts...

Answer (score 0):

Good idea! No, not currently - you could, of course, have a bunch of different icons there and switch the button out when the count changes, but it's not ideal.

I'll add it to our backlog.